# Question based on $\triangle$ and Arithmetic progression.

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c$ are the sides of a $\triangle ABC$ which are in Arithmetic progression. Then Range of $\displaystyle \frac{b}{c}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ In a Triangle Given that sides $a,b,c$ are in Arithmetic Progression.

So $2b=a+c\Rightarrow a=2b-c$

and In Triangle, $\displaystyle a+b>c\Rightarrow 2b-c+b>c\Rightarrow 3b>2c\Rightarrow \frac{b}{c}>\frac{2}{3}$

Now how can i calculate upper limit, Help required, Thanks

Comment: The upper limit is surely $1$, if $a \leq b \leq c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s:=\frac bc,t:=\frac ac$.

From $2b=a+c$, we have
$$2s=t+1\iff t=2s-1\tag1$$

From $$a+b\gt c,\quad b+c\gt a,\quad c+a\gt b$$
we have
$$t+s\gt 1,\quad s+1\gt t,\quad 1+t\gt s\tag2$$

From $(1)(2)$,
$$2s-1+s\gt 1,\quad s+1\gt 2s-1,\quad 1+2s-1\gt s,$$
to have
$$\color{red}{\frac 23\lt \frac bc\lt 2}$$